# MySQL pivot efficiency

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have a MySQL table of stock data organized like this:

```
ddate idnum open  high  low  close  volume
------------------------------------------
2001  1423  1     3     0    2      100
2002  1423  3     2     1    2      150
2003  1423  NaN   4     1    3      170
2001  9486  9     10    4    8      1000
2002  9486  7     9     3    9      1200
2003  9486  8     9     5    7      1500
```

I want to create a table openmatrix organized like this:

```
      1423   9486
     ____________
2001| 1      9
2002| 3      7
2003| NaN    8
```

Which contains just the open prices from the original table of data, with the IDNUM corresponding to columns and each row corresponding to a date. Here's my code:

```
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(idnum = ',
      idnum,
      ',open, NULL)) AS ''',
      idnum,''''
      )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM rawdatatable;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ddate , ', @sql, ' FROM rawdatatable GROUP BY ddate');
SELECT @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: not really. mysql doesn't support pivot queries, and doing arbitrary-column-count pivots is basically impossible. fixed-column pivots is doable, but the queries get EXTREMELY ugly, EXTREMELY fast. Generally, you should do pivoting in mysql in the client-side code. It's just easier.

Comment: The query its ok,just a dynamic pivot.An index on `(idnum,ddate)` might speed things up.Also http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: @Mihai, one month worth of daily data for all my stocks takes 13 minutes to pivot, and I lose connection to the server before a year's worth completes, so I am not sure optimization here is premature. You'd try `ALTER TABLE rawdatatable ADD INDEX (idnum,ddate);`?

Comment: Yeah add the index or create a new table with pivoted data so you wont have to pivot it each time.How many rows in your table?

Comment: 1,684,052 rows in my table.

Comment: I tried a sample `SELECT ddate , MAX(IF(idnum = 10001,open, NULL)) AS '10001',MAX(IF(idnum = 10025,open, NULL)) AS '10025' FROM rawdatatable GROUP BY ddate;`, without indexing this takes 7 seconds, with index on `(idnum,ddate)` it also takes 7 seconds, with index on `(idnum,ddate,open)` it takes 1.9 seconds.

Comment: @MarcB, The main reason I'm using MySQL is because the data is too large to pivot in Matlab, since I'd have to read the data into RAM to do anything with it in Matlab. My plan was to pivot and filter out irrelevant data in MySQL before accessing it with Matlab

Comment: As a follow on question, do you know what memory variables in `my.ini` I should try increasing to speed up the pivot? I increased  `key_buffer_size=8G`, should I try any others?